# Delay on screen lock until I move mouse

Tags: 16.04, lock-screen, lock

I have had a problem with my Ubuntu 16.04 workstation with the screen lock for several months. When I lock it, most of the time, I walk away and come back well after the time when it should be locked to see the screen showing what I left up on the screen. As soon as I click the mouse or keyboard it goes to the lock screen and I have to enter my password before using it. However, when I am away it is displaying the contents of my screen. This concerns me.

Is this a configuration error, a bug or what do I need to investigate this problem?

Comment: That sounds like your screen saver might be closing during your lock screen.  What screen saver are you running on your system?   I have seen and it has happened to me where xscreensaver dies while I am away and had to write a cron job to check it every so often.

Comment: I am using whatever is default with Unity and friends, at least when I installed the OS. That was probably 12.04 originally. I seem to recall  xscreensaver being a replacement, not the default.

Comment: Yeah, still sounds like the screen saver is dying while you are a way from your computer.  When you lock it, the screen saver is on, correct?

Comment: No, come to think of it, I haven't seen a Screensaver at all. When it locks successfully, I simply see the login screen. Maybe it isn't running at all?

Comment: You might want to look here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingScreenLocking

Comment: @flickerfly for improved security, use `vlock` rather than a screensaver.

Comment: Interesting, what are the security advantages. Link will do.

Comment: I looked at `vlock` and I cannot figure out how to make it lock a screen so no one sees your desktop.  It will lock any console / terminal window you have open.  It seems secure for that, but if you want it so that people cannot see your desktop, I cannot figure out `vlock` for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so until this bug is fixed, i made a quick and dirty script that wiggles the mouse by 1px every 185s (my screen lock is set at 3 mins), so worst case scenario screen will not be visibly locked for 6 mins.

Here is the essential part of the code:

```
user@somepc:~/bin$ cat ./jiggle.sh
#!/bin/bash

while :; do xdotool mousemove_relative 1 0 mousemove_relative -- -1 0; sleep 185; done
```

Then I added this script to the "startup programs" and never looked back..